# Earthquake alert iOS APP, how can we send push notification, and deliver to iPhone in one second (for life saving)

Tags: ios, iphone, background, push-notification, background-process

We are developing earthquake alert APP for government earthquake center,
as we tested, push notification speed from server to iPhone can be: from 2 to 25 secs. (different every time)

If we can successfully push earthquake message to iPhone in 2 secs,
users should have about 5 secs to run to safe places.
Push speed is crucial for earthquake alert APP.

Could you please help us:

001: Is that possible to purchase higher priority push notification service, or use emergency push server for quicker push speed?

002: Is that possible to write our own background APP and always use TCP socket, connect to our own alert socket server (even when iPhone screen is black),
  once earthquake happen, the alert socket server quickly trigger background APP to alert users? (skip APPLE push notification server, use our own server to notify users)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

1. Nope, the APN (Apple Push Notification) API is what it is and there are no `fast lanes`.
2. Also nope, Apple requires you to use APN to deliver push notifications:

From the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#push-notifications):

> **5.1 Apps that provide Push Notifications without using the Apple Push Notification (APN) API will be rejected**